# How does $? works with c exit codes?

Tags: c, bash

I have a program in C, which exits with code 1:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

...
datatype pop(stack* st){
    if (empty(st)) exit(1);
    return st->data[st->sp--];
}
...

int main(void){
    ...
    // a is empty at this time
    pop(a); 
    ...
    return 0;
}
```

And I have a bash script:

```
run() {
    gcc -Wall -W -Wshadow -g -c "$filename.c"                                                                                                        
    echo "Exit code $?"                                                                                                                  
    gcc -Wall -W -Wshadow -g "$filename.o" -o "$filename" -lm  
    ./"$filename"
}
```

When I run a program, I get `Exit code 0`, shouldn't I get `Exit code 1`?

Comment: Like many *nix commands, gcc returns "0" on success, else "1" for failure.  You can fine-tune this behavior using gcc's `-pass-exit-codes` flag.  So your when your `echo "Exit code $?"` displays `0`, it means everything went OK ;)

Comment: The Bash script seems to have invalid syntax for what probably should be a function declaration – it should be either `run() {...}` or `function run {...}` (or `function run() {...}`).

Comment: @BenjaminW. yes it's `run() {...}`, will edit.

Comment: `$?` is the exit for of the previous command. The exit code you're seeing is from `gcc`, not your program. Move the echo.

Comment: @ramazan793: Q: what is your "$?" reporting?  A: It's reporting the exit status *of your first gcc invocation*  *NOT* your program.  If you want to capture your program's status ... put "$?" after your program executes ;)  ALSO: As you're probably aware, you can combine both "compile" and "link" in the same gcc command, if you wish to.

Comment: @paulsm4 Got it. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As note by comments, the main issue with current script is that it shows the GCC status, and not the run status. Also note that putting the 'echo' will change the $?. Assuming you want a 'combo' function that will build, execute, and return the status

```
run () {
    gcc -Wall -W -Wshadow -g -c "$filename.c" || return $?
    gcc -Wall -W -Wshadow -g "$filename.o" -o "$filename" -lm  || return $?
    ./"$filename"
}
run
Status saved in $X
X=$?
echo "Status=$?
```

The status of the 'combo' is saved in X, zero if everything is OK, non-zero otherwise (including compile error, build error, etc.)

Comment: `echo "Exit code $?"` is fine so long as it is the next statement after the program invocation -- that will yield the previous exit code, not the exit code of echo

Comment: The challenge with the 'echo $?' and variant is how to do add a branch AFTER the echo based on the $?. 'echo $? ; [ $? = 4 ] && echo "Crash" will not print "Crash" even when the program return status 4.